# How to select columns, which DO NOT contain a specific character?

Tags: r

Consider a vector including predictor names for a `glm` analysis like as

```
    pred_vec <- c("var1", 
                  "var2", 
                  "var3", 
                  "var4", 
                  "var1*var2", 
                  "var1*var3", 
                  "var1*var4")
```

where * indicates the interaction between two predictors! I want to select those elements of pred_vec which do not contain *, i.e.

```
pred_vec_new <- c("var1", 
                  "var2", 
                  "var3", 
                  "var4")
```

I need it to construct my Dataset for `glm` as

```
Dataset <- Dataset[ , pred_vec_new]
```

Comment: `pred_vec[grep("*", pred_vec, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]`

Comment: or `pred_vec[!grepl("*", pred_vec, fixed = TRUE)]` and `Dataset[!grepl("*", pred_vec, fixed = TRUE)]`